# How to build multilevel routing with reversed parameter location?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

At the moment I am using .NET Core and have a custom routing. My controller method is `DeliveriesController`. I am building my URL so that the slug is in the query string: `http://localhost:45778/deliveries/mcdonald` . To have this endpoint available, I had to add a endpoint to `Startup.cs`

```cs
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "deliveries",
                                 pattern: "deliveries/{*slug}",
                                 defaults: new { controller = "Deliveries", action = "Index" });
```

I added another action to my controller

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Menu(string slug)
{
    // ...
}
```

I would like to access this action view `Controller/Slug/Menu` . I am able to access it via `Controller/Menu/Slug` . How I setup my routing so I can access menu action with parameter before it? For example `http://localhost:45778/deliveries/mcdonald/menu`

Comment: `pattern: "deliveries/{slug}/{action=Index}", defaults: new { controller = "Deliveries" }`

Comment: @vasily.sib THANK YOU!